# Complement of digress?

Tags: single-word-requests, complements

Is there a verb that means "to return from a digression"?  The best I can think of is a phrase like "Getting back on topic, . . ."

Comment: Technically "regress" could mean this, but it is never actually used this way.

Comment: Neither English, nor a single word, but 'Revenons à nos moutons.'

Comment: @Barrie "Let's return to our sheep"? Charming idiom, that. :)

Comment: to de-digress, just kidding.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite/complement of digressing is *sticking to the intended subject matter*.

As for the action of getting back to that position *after* a digression, OP's *"To get back on topic,..."*, or *"To return to the subject,..."* are perfectly normal. A possible one-word alternative might be...

> "**Refocussing**,..."

Answer (score 2):

*[Resume](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resume#Verb)* (“To start (something) again that has been stopped or paused from the point at which it was stopped or paused; continue, carry on”) and *[return](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/return#Verb)* occasionally are so used in phrases in fiction, like “After that digression he resumed...”, or a narrator might say, “To resume our story” or “To return to my point”.  *[Recollect](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recollect#Verb)*, in sense “To collect (things) together again”, and *[retrieve](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retrieve#Verb)* (“To remember or recall something”) also are used:  “Recollecting himself, he continued:”  or  “Retrieving his thoughts, he went on”.  All sorts of other phrases (but few single, unsupported verbs) are used:  “But where was I?”,  “Less digressively”, “More topically”, “But I digress”, “Resuming our thread”, “That aside”.

Answer (score 0):

Regress could work, but if you digress, then it's closer to deviate in its use in this sense.

So I don't think there is a single word for un-digress in this context.

In the sentence "let me just digress and speak about XYZ," you would use the sentence "anyway, to return to the main topic..." so I think "return" would work best as you are returning from a digression.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the phase, "Stepping out of a tangent." It's most likely not a common phrase, but a good one.

Comment: This would be an idiolect. It could be used, but it's not in general or even dialect-limited usage as the question is asking.